# python3: variable length values inside {} for print & .format()

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, string.format

Is there a way to create a formatted string in python with flexible {} adjustments?
The default way is:

```
In [1]: "{:20}Hey B! You are {} blocks away.".format("Hey A!", 20-6)
Out[1]: 'Hey A!              Hey B! You are 14 blocks away.'
```

But is there a way to code the "distance between A and B" flexible? Like this..?

```
#not working
In [2]: x = 20
In [3]: "{:x}Hey! You are {} blocks away.".format("Hey! A", x-6)
Out[3]: 'Hey A!              Hey B! You are 14 blocks away.'

In [2]: x = 30
In [3]: "{:x}Hey! You are {} blocks away.".format("Hey! A", x-6)
Out[3]: 'Hey A!                        Hey B! You are 14 blocks away.'
```

Or is there any other way simple and convenient way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python allows nested formatting operators. When operating positionally, each positional argument is counted by where its open brace appears. So to use `x` for justifying `"Hey! A"` as desired, you can do:

```
"{:{}}Hey! You are {} blocks away.".format("Hey! A", x, x-6)
   ^^ These brackets fill in the desired width using the second positional arg
```

If you want to avoid thinking about the numbering in this case, you can name the argument providing the width, passing it via keyword, e.g. `width`:

```
"{:{width}}Hey! You are {} blocks away.".format("Hey! A", x-6, width=x)
```

You can see more examples under ["Nesting arguments and more complex examples" here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty, but it's one way:

```
x = 20

("{:"+str(x)+"}Hey! You are {} blocks away.").format("Hey! A", x-6)

# 'Hey! A              Hey! You are 14 blocks away.'
```

Alternative syntax:

```
''.join(("{:", str(x), "}Hey! You are {} blocks away.")).format("Hey! A", x-6)
```

Comment: Downside to this approach is that the format string itself must be constructed anew each time. Nested formatting operators mean the format string remains a constant, producing a single result with no intermediate temporary strings; only the arguments vary each time.